# How can I get the ID name of DIV that is loaded dynamically using javascript and Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, razor, view

I have some Jquery code that I am trying to fix up. The ID names of the DIVS are loaded dynamically. I would like to be able to get the ID name on pageload so that I can force the DIV to display as soon as the page is opened. I think my first problem is this line of code   `var divId = '.$enrolment->id.'val();`. I doubt that line is correct.

MY Code So far

```
 for ($i = 0; $i < count($cat_array); $i++) {
                if ($enrolment->category == $cat_array[$i]) {
                    $first = true;
                         echo '<div id='.$enrolment->id.' class="tabcontent">';
                }
         }
    
       <script>
    
       function FormFunction() {
        var divId = "a" + '.$enrolment->id.'.attr("id");
        var currentDivId =  "#" + divId; 
            $('#currentDivId').hide();    
      }
        window.onload = FormFunction;
       </script>
```

Comment: A `div` cannot have a value, you need `.attr('id')`

Comment: `$('#currentDivId')` is treating that as a literal string selector.  It is not using the variable you just created of the same name.

Comment: Furthermore: `$enrolment->id` is php code you are using inside a JS block which will not work and is outside your loop, please have a look at client side vs server side coding

Comment: There are many issues here. I don't know where to begin to help on this.

Comment: If `$enrolment->id` is an int (id column)... then you will want to prefix that with a non-numeric character to be a valid html `id` value. Also, by the time you get to that `<script>` output (and you properly echo the value), you are only using the last enrolment id from the loop above. As well as the other issues the others have mentioned above. This... is ... a mess of errors :D

Comment: Please look at my changes in the update as well as the explanation. Apologies I am new to php